# CSS Grid Layout Sidebar toggle

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is a question regarding the new CSS Grid system that was recently added to the CSS web standards. This is an example of a layout that I am trying to use:

```css
html,body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 9fr 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" 
                      "main chat"
                      "footer footer";
}

.chat{
  grid-area: chat;
  background-color: brown; 
  overflow: auto;
}
.header{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: black;
}

.main{
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: maroon;
}

.footer{
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
   chat
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrKPLX?editors=1100)

Now I need to toggle the chat sidebar such that the main div occupies the remaining space. I already know how to do this in flexbox and JavaScript. However, I want to try this using CSS Grids.

One way would be to do this: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 0;`

But I want the chat sidebar to be toggled smoothly (like CSS transitions) rather than disappearing abruptly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make the grid adapt with auto, and change the .chat width

```css
html,body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100wh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 9fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" 
                      "main chat"
                      "footer footer";
}

.chat{
  grid-area: chat;
  background-color: brown; 
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.header{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: black;
}

.main{
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: maroon;
}

.footer{
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #222;
}

body:hover .chat {
width: 0px;  
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    main
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
   chat
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
```

Comment: And since the `fr` unit represents a proportion of the available space, `9fr` and `1fr` are the same in this case. In fact, since there is only one column using `fr`, *any* `fr` > 0 would do the same thing.

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, it probably would be better  to use 1fr. I just kept the original code.

Comment: Transitioning width is very heavy for the browser's paint engine though.

Comment: @vals how to do the same thing on the left side.

Comment: @kano "transitions are expensive" is largely a non-issue that has been fluffed up for years now. On real computers it is *not* an issue and on weak mobile devices like phones and tablets, users rarely/never resize stuff anyway.

Comment: @TylerH In isolation, sure. But in a web application or a website of moderate size and complexity, things pile up. Most websites do not handle resizing gracefully and it causes jitters/spikes in the re-renders. I'd bet trivial and fluffed up issues like transitioning width can take some of the blame there.